# nftable produce unexpected message in syslog

Tags: firewall, logging, nftables

I have the following nftables rule:
`log prefix "[nftables] output denied1: " ip daddr 34.117.59.81 reject`

in syslog i can see the message:
`[nftables] output denied1: IN= OUT=br0 SRC=10.10.10.1 DST=10.10.10.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=540 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=2 SEQ=60848`

Now i wonder how it is possible? In the syslog message there is `DST=10.10.10.4`, but the rule shouldn't be used for that destination address.

It would be realy cool, if anyone can explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Order does matter. In a single rule, each expression / (non-terminal) statement is evaluated in turn:

- if true, evaluation continues to the next expression/statement in the rule
- if false, evaluation ends

Most non-terminal statement are true (ie: rule evaluation continues). Anyway that's the case for the `log` statement: it always allows continuation of evaluation in the rule.

A `log` statement placed as the first part of the rule will do its role: generate logs. Without filter before it (or without being in a regular (aka user) chain called from a previous rule with such filter) *everything* will be logged. Then evaluation will continue to the actual filter: `ip daddr 34.117.59.81`. If this one evaluates true, `reject` will be done, else nothing more happens in this rule (and next rule if any is evaluated).

The fix is to always put the `log` statement *after* the condition it's supposed to log about and before the terminal statement (which won't allow further expressions/statements):

```
ip daddr 34.117.59.81 log prefix "[nftables] output denied1: " reject
```